# What's is scope of setSecurityManager in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I would like to enforce security manager for execution some 3rd party libraries classes, so I do something like that:

```
  SecurityManager original = System.getSecurityManager();
  System.setSecurityManager(for3rdOne);
  try {
      thirdparty.doStuff();
  } finally {
      System.setSecurityManager(original);
  }
```

So far, so good, the code works perfectly limiting 3rd parties to certain constraints. However I have several doubts I can't find answer:

1. What if I execute this code in several threads, so if setSecurityManager has global scope then returning original security manager will open breach for 3rd party?
2. if setSecurityManager has scope of only current thread, do I need to worry to return original security manager if my thread ends after calling 3rd party?
   Second doubt has certain trick for example new security manager `for3rdOne` doesn't allow calling `setSecurityManager` , so I need to do some action to allow it after my sand-boxed code exited.

Answer (score 0):

setSecurityManager has global scope, so the simplest solution is to `setSecurityManager(for3rdOne)` once and forever. If, however, some parts of your code should be executed under different security policy, then that code should synchronize with third party code. One solution is to start a special thread with input queue, which executes all the code sensitive to security policy. The thread can be considered as a single-threaded executor, but for a special class of tasks: each task has a property `securityManager` which is examined and used to call to `setSecurityManager` before the task is executed.

If there are too much of security-sensitive code and single thread becomes a bottleneck, more sophisticated solutions can be elaborated, but I believe there is no universal solution, more information required to give an advice. Most parallel solution is to use separate JVM for each kind of security manager, but this may be inappropriate because of large amount of data floating between processes.

Update

the easiest way to differentiate security policy for different callers is to assign different permissions to different threads - because it is easy to determine current thread, and then determine its type (class or interface). Another way is read current context with [SecurityManager.getSecurityContext()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html#getSecurityContext%28%29), scan it and check if there are classes with restricted capabilities.

Comment: Are there any solution when Security Manager can analyze context of class loader to make a decision? For example in my case I use a separate class loader for 3rd party so it could be a good opportunity.

Comment: Security context is just an object. So if by any chance you have a reference to particular implementation, would you mind to share? I just do not want to invent a wheel.  I am interested in base entry point to maintain the context.

Comment: I am confused. Your question was about SecurityManager, which is part of JavaSE. Now you are talking about Security context, which is another thing and is a part of JavaEE: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/resource/spi/work/SecurityContext.html

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at `ProtectionDomain` and `CodeSource`. These allow you to setup different permission based on package names or originating code URL.